# why the hadoop output file part-r-00000 is empty

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

my MR logs is :

```
[root@sicongli hadoop-2.4.1]# hadoop jar flowcount.jar   
cn.itheima.bigdata.hadoop.mr.flowcount.FlowCount /data/join.txt /out
16/04/13 23:32:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop
library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/04/13 23:32:22 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at sicongli/192.168.218.111:8032

16/04/13 23:32:28 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/04/13 23:32:35 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/04/13 23:32:38 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/04/13 23:32:41 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1460601112521_0002
16/04/13 23:32:47 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1460601112521_0002
16/04/13 23:32:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://sicongli:8088/proxy/application_1460601112521_0002/
16/04/13 23:32:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1460601112521_0002
16/04/13 23:35:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1460601112521_0002 running in uber mode : false
16/04/13 23:35:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/04/13 23:36:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/04/13 23:37:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/04/13 23:37:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1460601112521_0002 completed successfully
16/04/13 23:38:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 49
    File System Counters
            FILE: Number of bytes read=6
            FILE: Number of bytes written=186579
            FILE: Number of read operations=0
            FILE: Number of large read operations=0
            FILE: Number of write operations=0
            HDFS: Number of bytes read=399
            HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
            HDFS: Number of read operations=6
            HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
            HDFS: Number of write operations=2
    Job Counters 
            Launched map tasks=1
            Launched reduce tasks=1
            Data-local map tasks=1
            Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=17296
            Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=36727
            Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=17296
            Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=36727
            Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=17296
            Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=36727
            Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=17711104
            Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=37608448
    Map-Reduce Framework
            Map input records=23
            Map output records=0
            Map output bytes=0
            Map output materialized bytes=6
            Input split bytes=99
            Combine input records=0
            Combine output records=0
            Reduce input groups=0
            Reduce shuffle bytes=6
            Reduce input records=0
            Reduce output records=0
            Spilled Records=0
            Shuffled Maps =1
            Failed Shuffles=0
            Merged Map outputs=1
            GC time elapsed (ms)=217
            CPU time spent (ms)=1150
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=277962752
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=1689296896
            Total committed heap usage (bytes)=127127552
    Shuffle Errors
            BAD_ID=0
            CONNECTION=0
            IO_ERROR=0
            WRONG_LENGTH=0
            WRONG_MAP=0
            WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
            Bytes Read=300
    File Output Format Counters 
            Bytes Written=0
16/04/13 23:38:18 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: sicongli/192.168.218.111:49806. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/04/13 23:38:19 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: sicongli/192.168.218.111:49806. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/04/13 23:38:20 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: sicongli/192.168.218.111:49806. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/04/13 23:38:23 INFO mapred.ClientServiceDelegate: Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
```

and the output is :

```
[root@sicongli ~]# hadoop fs -ls /out
16/04/14 00:00:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup          0 2016-04-13 23:37 /out/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup          0 2016-04-13 23:37 /out/part-r-00000
```

and i have tow issue:

one ： why the output file part-r-0000 is empty

tow : why there is the warn:    INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: sicongli/192.168.218.111:49806. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1 - read the counters:

> Map input records=23
>
> Map output records=0

Part-r-00000 is empty, because nothing is making it out of your map task. If you add the code of your map task to your post, we might be able to tell you *why*.

Question 2 - read the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24107091/2363967) question, they might help you out.

Comment: and how about my tow problem

Comment: Try updating to Hadoop 2.7.2. If that's not an option, try disabling the firewall on your computer.

Comment: now i have got the result . but the info : INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: sicongli/192.168.218.111:49806. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)       is always have .   my firewall is off

Comment: That's listed as a bug in particular versions of Hadoop, up to 2.6.0 - that's why I suggested trying 2.7.2. Seeing as you're running the task on a local machine, I don't think that should affect your final result anyway.