# NodeManager and ResourceManager processes do not start

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am setting up a Multi-Node cluster and my NodeManager and ResourceManager processes are not starting for some reason and I can't figure out why. When I run the `jps` command, I only see the `NameNode` and `SecondaryNameNode` and `JPS` processes. As a result, my MapReduce job won't work. This is my configuration

yarn-site.xml - across NameNode and DataNodes

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>ec2PathToMyNameNode.compute-1.amazonaws.com</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

And my hosts file is this on the NameNode:

```
nameNodeIP nameNodePublicDNS.compute-1.amazonaws.com
dataNode1IP dataNode1PublicDNS.compute-1.amazonaws.com
dataNode2IP dataNode2PublicDNS.compute-1.amazonaws.com
dataNode3IP dataNode3PublicDNS.compute-1.amazonaws.com
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

When I run my MapReduce job it says it's unable to connect at `8032`. I am using Hadoop 3.1.2

**Edit:**

I Checked the logs and i found the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>       ... 83 more
>
> Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver.(JAXBContextResolver.java:41)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebApp.setup(RMWebApp.java:54)
>     while locating org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver
>
> 1 error
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
>       at com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory$GuiceInstantiatedComponentProvider.getInstance(GuiceComponentProviderFactory.java:345)

Comment: what is the command used to start hadoop; start-dfs.sh or start-all.sh?

Comment: I have been using both, lol. Wasn't sure which is best.

Comment: what is the log directory you specified? check the `HADOOP_LOG_DIR` global variable value

Comment: You have to check the Hadoop log directory, it contains the errors thrown by Nodemanager and resourcemanager when they try to start

Comment: I only set HADOOP_CONF_DIR and HADOOP_HOME. Do I need to execute the formatting of hdfs in a specific directory?

Comment: Which hadoop version you are using

Comment: Check my edit for the log message, please.

Comment: There are more exceptions can you provide them?

Comment: Ok, just did now.

Comment: Try to search for these exceptions, i found some links that can help: (1) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14978 
 (2) https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-8802

Comment: Thanks, you helped me figure it out. I wouldn't have thought about the logs.

Comment: I will try to sum all what we mentioned in the comments inside an well formatted answer so other users will benefit from it easly, and you have to write your own answer when you solves the issue.

Comment: check the third suggestion in my answer, i didn't mention it in the comments, also check the links i provided

Answer (score 2):

## Trying to figure out the issue

**(1) Start-dfs.sh vs Start-all.sh**

Check that you are using `Start-all.sh` command when you are trying to start hadoop because `Start-dfs.sh` will only start the namenode and datanodes

**(2) Check the Hadoop logs**

Check for the `HADOOP_LOG_DIR` global variable value to get the Log dir, because it will include all exception thrown when trying to start the Namenode Manager and the Resource Manager

**(3) Check for the installed Java version**

The error may be thrown by an incompatible Java version, check that you have installed the latest Java version.

- [Fix Java 9 incompatibilies in Hadoop](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11123)
- [Hadoop Error starting ResourceManager and NodeManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427653/hadoop-error-starting-resourcemanager-and-nodemanager)

**(4) Check Hadoop Common issues**

Based on the error you provided in the answer update you may find these issue links relevant:

- [[JDK9] Fail to run yarn application after building hadoop pkg with jdk9 in jdk9 env](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-8802)
- [[JDK9] Resource Manager failed to start after using hadoop pkg(built with jdk9)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14978)

---

## More information

For more information you can check my article on Medium, it may give you some insights:

- [Installing Hadoop 3.1.0 multi-node cluster on Ubuntu 16.04 Step by Step](https://medium.com/@hadi.fadlullah/installing-hadoop-3-1-0-multi-node-cluster-on-ubuntu-16-04-step-by-step-8d1954b31505)

Answer (score 1):

my problem is that I used java11 to cooperate with hadoop.

so what i do is

1.rm /Library/Java/*

2.download java8 from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

3.install java8jdk and

4.fix the JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh

5.stop-all.sh

6.start-dfs.sh

7.start-yarn.sh

Comment: More explanation on what each step does or what its purpose would be tremendously helpful!

Answer (score -1):

[pdash@localhost hadoop]$ export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM"
[pdash@localhost hadoop]$ export YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS="--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM"

It will work for sure I tried from apache JIRA log ....Thank PRAFUL